# How do I (re)write bytes in the middle of a file?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, io

I have a case where there are a block of bytes in the middle of a file that need to be shuffled. Currently the implementation reads the file, shuffles the bytes in memory, then outputs the whole file. While this works it does not scale for larger file sizes. I have yet to find a C++ API that allows me to write a specific number of bytes to a file at a specific offset without also affecting the bytes that come after.

Can this be done?

Comment: Just use `seekg` and then write at the new position. Bytes that come after won't be affected.

Comment: If you need to _add_ or _remove_ bytes in the middle, that's a limitation of filesystems, not the C++ API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with an `fstream` (not `ifstream` or `ofstream`) since you're doing both input and output.

To do the shuffling, you basically need to use `seekg` to get to where you want to start changing things. Then use `read` to read the data you're going to shuffle. Then shuffle the data in memory, use `seekp` to seek back to where you want to write that data back out, and finally use `write` to put the shuffled data back in the file.

Here's a quick demo, taking the "shuffle" part literally -- it writes a string to a file, then reads some of the data in, sorts those bytes, and writes them back out:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void init(std::string const &name) { 
    std::ofstream initial(name);

    initial << "This is the initial data.";
}

void shuffle(std::string const &name) {
    std::fstream s(name);

    s.seekg(2);
    std::vector<char> data(5);
    s.read(&data[0], 5);
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    s.seekp(2);
    s.write(&data[0], 5);
}

void show(std::string const &name) { 
    std::ifstream in(name);

    std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in),
              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
}

int main() { 
    std::string name("e:/c/source/trash.txt");
    init(name);

    shuffle(name);

    show(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a platform that supports `mmap()` (Linux and other unix-likes - but I'm pretty sure That Other OS has a similar API, even if it's not called `mmap()`), just map the file (or the appropriate portion of it) into your address space, then shuffle in place.